# Is there a overall explanation about definitional scoping in Rebol and Red

Tags: scope, rebol, red

From the [REBOL/Core Users Guide](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-9.html#section-9), and [What is Red](http://static.red-lang.org/Recode2013-Red.pdf), I have learned that both Rebol and Red use **definitional scoping**.

From the guide, I know it is a form of **static scoping**, "the scope of a variable is determined when its context is defined", and is also called [**runtime lexical scoping**](http://www.rebol.com/r3/notes/errors.html), and is [a dynamic form of static scoping that depends on context 
definitions](https://www.mail-archive.com/list@rebol.com/msg08421.html).

I know in com-sci, there are two forms of scoping: lexical scoping (static scoping) and dynamic scoping. This *definitional scoping* confused me.

So what is definitional scoping?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Rebol actually does not have scoping at all.*

Let's take this code:

```
rebol []

a: 1

func-1: func [] [a]

inner: context [
    a: 2
    func-2: func [] [a]
    func-3: func [/local a] [a: 3 func-1]
]
```

So, with that code loaded, if Rebol had lexical scoping, this is what you'd see:

```
>> reduce [func-1 inner/func-2 inner/func-3]
== [1 2 1]
```

That would be because `func-1` uses the `a` from the outer scope, the `a` used by `func-2` is from the inner scope, and `func-3` calls `func-1`, which still uses `a` from the outer scope where it was defined regardless of what's in `func-3`.

If Rebol had dynamic scoping, this is what you'd see:

```
>> reduce [func-1 inner/func-2 inner/func-3]
== [1 2 3]
```

That would be because `func-3` redefines `a`, then calls `func-1`, which just uses the most recent active definition of `a`.

Now for Rebol, you get that first result. But Rebol doesn't have lexical scoping. So why?

Rebol fakes it. Here's how it works.

In compiled languages, you have scopes. As the compiler goes through the file, it keeps track of the current scope, then when it sees a nested scope that becomes the current scope. For lexical scoping, the compiler keeps a reference to the outer scope, and then looks up words that weren't defined in the current scope by following the links to the outer scopes, until it finds the word, or doesn't. Dynamic-scoped languages do something similar, but at runtime, going up the call stack.

Rebol doesn't do any of that; in particular it isn't compiled, it's built, at runtime. What you think of as code is actually data, blocks of words, numbers and such. The words are data structures that have a pointer in them called a "binding".

When that script is first loaded all the words in the script are added to the environment object of the script (which we inappropriately call a "context", though it's not). While the words are being gathered, the script data is changed. Any word found in the script's "context" is linked to the "context", or "bound". Those bindings mean that you can just follow that one link and get to the object where the value of that word is stored. It's really fast.

Then, once that's done, we start running the script. And then we get to this bit: `func [] [a]`. That is not really a declaration, that's a call to a function named `func` which takes a spec block and a code block and uses them to build a function. That function also gets its own environment object, but with words declared in the function's spec. In this case there are no words in the spec, so it's an empty object. Then the code block is bound to that object. But in this case there is no `a` in that object, so nothing is done to the `a`, *it keeps the binding it already had from when it was bound before*.

Same goes for the `context [...]` call - yes, that's a call to a function inappropriately named `context`, which builds an object by calling `make object!`. The `context` function takes a block of data, and it searches for set-words (those things with the trailing colons, like `a:`), then builds an object with those words in it, then it binds all of the words in that block and all the nested blocks to the words that are in the object, in this case `a`, `func-2` and `func-3`. And that means that the `a`'s in that block of code have their bindings *changed*, to point to that object instead.

When `func-2` is defined, the binding of the `a` in its code block is not overridden. When `func-3` is defined, it has an `a` in its spec, so the `a:` has its binding overridden.

The funny thing about all of this is that *there aren't any scopes at all*. That first `a:` and the `a` in `func-1`'s code body are only bound once, so they keep their first binding. The `a:` in `inner`'s code block and the `a` in `func-2`'s are bound twice, so they keep their second binding. The `a:` in `func-3`'s code is bound three times, so it also keeps its last binding. It's not scopes, it's just code being bound and then smaller bits of code being bound again, and so on until it's done.

Each round of binding is performed by a function that is "defining" something (really, building it), and then when that code runs and calls other functions that define something else, those functions perform another round of binding to its little subset of code. That's why we call it "definitional scoping"; while it really isn't scoping, it is what serves the purpose of scoping in Rebol, and it's close enough to the behavior of lexical scoping that on first glance you can't tell the difference.

It really becomes different when you realize that these bindings are direct, *and you can change them* (sort of, you can make new words with the same name and a different binding). That same function that those definition functions call, you can call yourself: it's named `bind`. With `bind` you can break the illusion of scoping and make words that bind to any object you can get access to. You can do wonderful tricks with `bind`, even make your own definition functions. It's loads of fun!

As for Red, Red is compilable, but it also includes a Rebol-like interpreter, binding and all of the goodies. When it's defining things with the interpreter it does definitional scoping as well.

Does that help make things more clear?

Comment: Thank you BrianH for the great explanation. But wouldn't be better using "make object! []" or "context" instead of "object []", so it would be compatible with Rebol2 too?

Comment: Darn, I thought that had made it into the backported functions. I'll switch it to `context`, and move the comment about it being a function to talk about `func` instead.

Comment: It's the clearest description on the topic to time! Thanks BrianH for taking effort.

It think mentioning Ladislav's well-known, more detailed, but harder to digest http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Bindology article on the same page might help discovering your explanation easier by beginners.

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, and @BrianH's answer here is very thorough on mechanics.  But I thought I would give one with a slightly different focus, as a bit more of a "story".

In Rebol, there is a category of types called **words**.  These are essentially symbols, so their string content is scanned and they go into a symbol table.  So whereas `"FOO"` would be a string, and `<FOO>` would be another "flavor" of string known as a tag... `FOO`, `'FOO`, `FOO:` and `:FOO` are all various "flavors" of words with the same symbol ID.  *(A "word", a "lit-word", a "set-word", and a "get-word" respectively.)*

Being collapsed to a symbol makes it impossible to modify the name of a word once loaded.  They're stuck, compared with strings that each have their own data and are mutable:

```
>> append "foo" "bar"
== "foobar"

>> append 'foo 'bar
** Script error: append does not allow word! for its series argument
```

Immutability has an advantage, in that as a symbol it's fast to compare one word to another.  But there is another piece of the puzzle: each instance of a word can optionally have an invisible property in it called a **binding**.  That binding lets it "point at" a key/value entity known as a **context** where a value can be read or written.

> *Note: Unlike @BrianH I do not think that calling this category of binding targets "contexts" is all that bad--at least I don't think it today.  Ask me later, I might change my mind if new evidence comes to light.  Suffice to say it's an object-like thing, but not always an object...it might be a reference into a function's frame on the stack, for instance.*

Whoever brings a word into the system gets the first shot at saying what context it gets bound to.  A lot of that time that's LOAD, so if you said `load "[foo: baz :bar]"` and got back the 3-word block `[foo: baz :bar]` they would be bound into the "user context", with a fallback to the "system context".

Following the binding is how everything works, and each "flavor" of word does something different.

```
>> print "word pointing to function runs it"
word pointing to function runs it

>> probe :print "get-word pointing to function gets it"
make native! [[
    "Outputs a value followed by a line break."
    value [any-type!] "The value to print"
]]
== "get-word pointing to function gets it"
```

> *Note: The second case didn't print that string.  It probed the function specification, then the string was just the last thing in the evaluation so it evaluated to that.*

But once you've got a block of data with words in it in your hands, the bindings are anybody's game.  As long as a context has the symbol for a word in it, you can retarget that word to that context.  *(Assuming also that the block hasn't been protected or locked against modification...)*

This cascading chain of rebinding opportunities is the important point.  Since FUNC is a "function generator" that takes a spec and a body that you give it, it has the ability to take the "raw matter" of the body with its bindings and override whichever ones it decides to.  Eerie perhaps, but look at this:

```
>> x: 10

>> foo: func [x] [
    print x
    x: 20
    print x
]

>> foo 304
304
20

>> print x
10
```

What happened was that FUNC received two blocks, one representing a parameter list and the second representing a body.  When it got the body, both the `print`s were bound to the native printing function *(in this case--and it's important to point out that when you're getting material from places other than the console they could each be bound differently!)*.  `x` was bound to the user context *(in this case)* which was holding the value 10.  If FUNC didn't do anything to change the situation, things would stay that way.

But it put the picture together and decided that since the parameter list had an x in it, that it would look through the body and *overwrite* the words with the symbol ID for x with a new binding...local to the function.  That's the only reason that it didn't overwrite the global with `x: 20`.  Had you omitted the [x] in the spec FUNC wouldn't have done anything, and it would have been overwritten.

Each piece in the chain of definition gets an opportunity before passing things on.  Hence **definitional scoping**.

> FUN FACT: Since if you don't supply parameters to the spec of FUNC, it won't rebind anything in the body, this led to mistaken impressions that *"everything in Rebol is in global scope"*.  But that's not true at all because as @BrianH says: *"Rebol actually does not have scoping at all (...) Rebol fakes it."*   In fact, that's what FUNCTION (as opposed to FUNC) does--it goes hunting in the body for set-words like **x:**, and when it sees them adds them to the local frame and binds to them.  The effect looks like local scope, but again, it is not!

If it sounds a bit Rube-Goldberg-esque to imagine these symbols with invisible pointers being shuffled around, *that's because it is*.  To me personally, the remarkable thing is sort of that it works at all...and I've seen people pull stunts with it that you wouldn't intuitively think such a simple trick could be used to do.

Case in point: the maddeningly useful COLLECT and KEEP ([Ren-C version](https://trello.com/c/H9I0261r)):

```
collect: func [
    {Evaluates a block, storing values via KEEP function,
        and returns block of collected values.}
    body [block!] "Block to evaluate"
    /into {Insert into a buffer instead
             (returns position after insert)}
    output [any-series!] "The buffer series (modified)"
][
    unless output [output: make block! 16]
    eval func [keep <with> return] body func [
        value [<opt> any-value!] /only
    ][
        output: insert/:only output :value
        :value
    ]
    either into [output] [head output]
]
```

This unassuming-looking tool extends the language in the following style *(again, Ren-C version... in R3-Alpha or Rebol2 substitute [`foreach` for `for-each`](https://trello.com/c/cxvHGNha) and [`length?` for `length of`](https://trello.com/c/4OT7qvdu))*

```
>> collect [
       keep 10
       for-each item [a [b c] [d e f]] [
           either all [
               block? item
               3 = length of item
           ][
               keep/only item
           ][
               keep item
           ]
       ] 
    ]
== [10 a b c [d e f]]
```

The trick here with definitional scoping is understood best by what I mentioned above.  FUNC will only overwrite the bindings of things in its parameter list and leave everything else in the body untouched.  So what happens is that it takes the body you passed to COLLECT and uses that as the body of a new function, where it overwrites any bindings of KEEP.  It then sets KEEP to a function that adds data to an aggregator when called.

Here we see the KEEP function's versatility in splicing blocks into the collected output or not, via an /ONLY switch *(the caller chose to not splice only if we see an item of length 3)*.  But this is only scratching the surface.  It's just *one* deeply powerful language feature--added by users after the fact--originating from so little code it's almost scary.  There are certainly many more stories.

I'm here adding an answer due to having filled in a crucial missing link for definitional scoping, a problem known as the "definitionally scoped return":

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109443/definitional-returns-solved-mostly

This is why the `<with> return` is alongside the KEEP in the spec.  It's there because COLLECT is trying to tell FUNC it wants to "use its services" as a binder-and-runner-of code.  But the body was already authored somewhere else by someone else.  So if it has a RETURN in it, then that RETURN already has an idea of where to return to.  FUNC is only to "re-scope" the keep, but leave any returns alone instead of adding its own.  Hence:

```
>> foo: func [x] [
     collect [
         if x = 10 [return "didn't collect"]
         keep x
         keep 20
     ]
]

>> foo 304
== [304 20]

>> foo 10
== "didn't collect"
```

It is `<with> return` that makes COLLECT able to be smart enough to know that inside FOO's body, it didn't want the return rebound so that it thought to return from the function whose parameter was just [keep] instead.

And there's a little bit about the "why" of definitional scoping, vs. just the "what".  :-)

Comment: @klausnrooster Thanks, though I should probably update this, I've found a few other things out since.  But you may also find [Rebol vs. Lisp Macros](http://blog.hostilefork.com/rebol-vs-lisp-macros/) interesting...

Comment: Ha, the word 'this' is linked to that very page. I should be more explicit.

Comment: @klausnrooster ah, hard to see the link (and doesn't show in notifications)!  Well, I wrote that too... :-)

Comment: Don't try to fix what is fundamentally broken, that's all I have to say.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Is painting fundamentally broken, and we should all use [SolidWorks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX9cFW5iZSY), having every equation and symmetry captured so nothing gets out of sync?  I guess no one should waste their life with galleries or literature, then.  Or perhaps everyone who does do art should think M.C. Escher is the pinnacle of it...and/or do everything in Haskell?  Programming is an *art form* and learning the higher levels of it is a lot like learning how to break rules in other art.  [Maybe someday you'll get there.](https://trello.com/c/Bu40ecLC)  :-P

Comment: Painting is not fundamentally broken and Escher is certainly not the pinnacle of it. Breaking rules is nice if you're in computer science, but for general programming you should try and adhere to the structure that the language defines as much as possible. Stepping outside it will lead to (subtle) bugs and unmaintainable code. But yeah, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is:

Rebol is Statically Scoped

but,

The question is not “what scoping does Rebol employ?”, but, “when is Rebol scoping determined, when is a Rebol program compiled?”.

Rebol has static scoping, but dynamic compilation.

We are accustomed to there being one compilation time and one run time.

Rebol has multiple compilation times.

The compilation of Rebol code depends on the context that exists at the time of compilation.

Rebol code is compiled at different times, within different contexts. This means that Rebol functions might be compiled differently at different times.