# How to extend object by adding a function, and then access original object using self?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm defining a simple object with two fields.  Later I want to extend it with a function that can read those fields.  *(For the moment, let's say it just wants to print one of them out.)*

```
email-service!: context [ 
    key: "abcd" 
    secret: "" 
] 

extend email-service! 'get-folders does [print self/key]

my_email: make email-service! [
    key: "asdfasdf" 
    secret: "who knows?" 
] 

my_email/get-folders
```

The expected output is "asdfasdf", but instead, nothing is printed out.

As a slight twist, replace the "does" with a function:

```
extend email-service! 'get-folders func [] [print self/key]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the workings of ["definitional scoping"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964110/is-there-a-overall-explanation-about-definitional-scoping-in-rebol-and-red/21964858#21964858)...your routine defined as `does [print self/key]` did binding into the enclosing context.  That context could be a module or some context we can't see here.

But let's introduce a manual context just to show what I mean:

```
context [
    key: "OUTER CONTEXT KEY"

    email-service!: context [ 
       key: "abcd" 
       secret: "" 
    ] 

    extend email-service! 'get-folders does [print self/key]

    my_email: make email-service! [
        key: "asdfasdf" 
        secret: "who knows?" 
    ] 

    my_email/get-folders 
]
```

That will give you **"OUTER CONTEXT KEY"** as output.  This function you are defining only knows about its enclosing context, it doesn't know you will later be passing it by parameter to become a new member of `email-service!`.

But obviously your question isn't about how to put the function inside the definition of email-service!.  You want to add it after-the-fact.  How to connect it up to know about email-service?  *By explicitly binding the body of the function where you want it.*

```
email-service!: context [ 
    key: "abcd" 
    secret: "" 
] 

extend email-service! 'get-folders does bind [print key] email-service!

my_email: make email-service! [
    key: "asdfasdf" 
    secret: "who knows?" 
] 

my_email/get-folders
```

That should get you the desired **"asdfasdf"**.  If you wanted to do it with a function you would do the same...bind the body:

```
extend email-service! 'get-folders func [] bind [print key] email-service!
```

It's up to you to decide whether to bind the self word to email-service! and use it.  You don't need it here *(notice that I say `print key` and not `print self/key`)*.  Just remember that every word you deal with can have a binding for evaluation...and it can be different even for words with the same spelling in code composed from multiple contexts.