# What is the difference between `context` and `object`?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

In Rebol 3, there are the functions `object` and `context`.

**What's the purpose of the difference?**

*Note* : for reference, in red, both are the same, and `object` doesn't exist
in rebol 2

#### Context: *no pun intended*

Initially, I was wondering why we had `context` instead of `make object!`

Now, after learning of the `object` word used to make objects,
I'm curious to know why they are all different and the *rationale* for having different things to `make` the same thing.

Note that in rebol3:

```
object: make function! [[
    "Defines a unique object."
    blk [block!] "Object words and values (modified)"
][
    make object! append blk none
]]
```

*It `append`s `none` to the block*. Why? Is this just a minor difference?
Does it deserve a separate question?

In all 3:

```
context: make function! [[
    "Defines a unique object."
    blk [block!] "Object words and values (modified)"
][
    make object! blk
]]
```

P.S. slight differences in construction between the versions

Comment: Note that terminology-wise, there is opposition to the "nounishness" of OBJECT.  Object is a good name for an object itself as opposed to the operation creating them.  If you are naming parameters to functions you then are unlikely to want to say **function [object [object!]] [...]** and override the "verb".  *(There's precedent with FUNCTION, but that's based on a long history of the word, and for that reason some thought to call the datatype ACTION! so at least a noun doesn't overlap a type name.)*  Ren-C is trying CONSTRUCT (arity 2) and HAS (arity 1).

Answer (score 5):

`context` was historically introduced in Rebol2 as a shortcut to `make object!`, and to better signify the intent of using the object to provide a [definitionally scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21964858/2081311) namespace for organizing user code.

`object` was added in Rebol3 in order to provide a more natural name for the shortcut and be more useful when constructing the object dynamically using `collect-words` for example.

Red should be using the Rebol3 `object` definition, as it provides that handy extra feature.

Answer (score 3):

`context` and `object` serves same functionality. `context` is from Rebol2 and I think it is exists in Rebol3 and Red for backward compatibility.

`object` exists in Rebol3 and Red and almost same (in R3 version it supports `object [a: b: c:]` style, no big difference)

So you can use any of them. I personally like `context`.

Comment: There is the difference in `make`ing in rebol3: `append blk none` vs `blk`

Comment: I think the only difference is that it support `object [a: b: c:]` otherwise we should write `object [a: b: c: none]`. I see no other difference.