# Is it possible in Red to test value? for a variable inside a context not in global context?

Tags: red

In last example, probe value? 'a returns true as it detects 'a has value in global context. But I'd like to test 'a exclusively in local context, is there a syntax to do so ?

```
    context [
        probe value? 'a; false
    ]

    context [
        a: 1
        probe value? 'a; true
    ]

    ; would like false instead of true
    a: 1
    context [
        probe value? 'a; true
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible in Red to test value? for a variable inside a context not in global context?

By definition, no.  Because there is no such thing as "the global context".

Remember that *"Rebol (Red) actually does not have scope at all"* ... *"Rebol (Red) fakes it."*

(See: [Is there a overall explanation about definitional scoping in Rebol and Red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964110/is-there-a-overall-explanation-about-definitional-scoping-in-rebol-and-red))

Rebol has BIND? for asking an arbitrary ANY-WORD! where it's bound to (if anywhere).  Red calls this CONTEXT?.  So what you can do is ask if the binding of a word is to a context you care about.

```
ctx1: context [a: 10]
ctx2: context [a: 20]

word: bind 'a ctx1

print ctx1 = context? word ; true
print ctx2 = context? word ; false
```

So if what you mean by "global context" is actually the so-called SYSTEM/WORDS object, then that can be your test:

```
context [
    probe value? 'a ; false
]

context [
    a: 1
    probe system/words <> context? 'a ; true
]

a: 1
context [
    probe system/words <> context? 'a ; false
]
```

As to whether this is appropriate for your purposes, I don't know.  Just remember there's no scope in Rebol/Red, unless you rig up some fake approximation that works well enough for what you're doing.

Comment: `Red doesn't have that (yet?)` isn't `context?` native does what you want?

Comment: @user310291 See [update with CONTEXT? operation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47245754/revisions), didn't know they'd renamed BIND? to that.

Comment: @HostileFork thanks context? seems that's what I want :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest check would be

```
context [
    probe in self 'a ; none
]
```

It returns `none` instead of `false`, but that is the only other falsy value anyway, so it's totally appropriate to check against. If you *need* it to be `false`, you can put `to-logic` in front.

Comment: really better. I was just before to add it.

Comment: I did very similar one without seeing yours: `>> a: 1 context [probe same? self context? 'a]  ; >> false`

Comment: @daveanderson I don't understand even context [(a: 1) probe in self 'a] returns none whereas it shouldn't since there is a: 1 ?

Comment: @user310291 I'm not sure about that one, but I notice that when you evaluate it, the returned object doesn't have an `a` value, so the parens must be preventing that word from being defined in the object. You could `compose` the block before it is given to `context` and the parens will be evaluated beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution without searching in the 'global' **system/words**, but in the 'local' **self**

```
>> a: 1
== 1
>> context [
[        probe all [
[            find words-of self 'a 
[            value? pick find words-of self 'a 1
[        ]
[        probe value? 'a
[    ]
none
true
== make object! []
>> 
>> context [
[        probe all [
[            find words-of self 'a 
[            value? pick find words-of self 'a 1
[        ]
[        probe value? 'a
[        a: 2
[    ]
none
false
== make object! [
   a: 2
]
>> 
>> context [
[        a: 2
[        probe all [
[            find words-of self 'a 
[            value? pick find words-of self 'a 1
[        ]
[        probe value? 'a
[    ]
true
true
== make object! [
    a: 2
]
```

Comment: that's ok if I know the value of 'a in advance only ?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: I want to test if variable a has been declared within local context whatever the value of a: 1, 2, "test" ... in your example you test for value a=1 ? Or I misunderstood ?

Comment: No, I test for existence of the word **a** in words-of object at first, then if the existent word has a value. I see there are some relics in my answer. I will correct that